# What is the type of "char board[N][N]"?

Tags: c, arrays

If i will declare array in the following way:

```
#define N 10

char board[N][N]
```

And I want to write function `void read_input(...)` that will get the array `board`, what I need to write instead `...` ?

I don't sure what it's need to be (maybey `char**` or `char[N][N]`? or else something?)

Comment: The type of `char board[N][N]`, is, unsurprisingly, `char[N][N]`. If you're asking about the type of a pointer `char[N][N]` decays to, then the answer is `char(*)[N]` (note that's it's the *left* `[N]` that's removed). You could pass it as `char x[N][N]` or `char (*x)[N]` (the first one is no different from and is automatically converted to the second one).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: And the function definition and prototype could also use `char board[][N]` for the parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Since the array size is a compile time constant, you can denote the array with that size when it is passed to your function.

```
void read_input(char board[N][N])
{
   ...
}


read_input(board);
```

Comment: and if `N` is defined in the following way `#define N 10` ?

Comment: In that case, since `N` is a macro representing a compile time constant, you can simply pass in the array specifying the size: `read_input(char board[N][N])`

Comment: @Mathing: if the dimensions are constant, you don't have to use the `*` notation; that is for variable-length arrays.

Comment: @dbush can you edit your answer in according to this case?

Comment: `cha board[*][*]` will not compile,  the `char [*]` is an incomplete type,  you can't make an array of incomplete types.

Comment: @Mathing Updated to reflect the updated requirement.

Comment: @KamilCuk `void read_input(int, char board[*][*]);` does in fact compile.  As a function declaration, it means that the dimensions of the array are defined by parameters specified earlier.

Comment: @KamilCuk, `char board[*][*]` is fine (for a function parameter), provided that the implementation supports VLAs and is conforming.

Comment: @KamilCuk: You can use the `char array[*][*]` notation in function declarations to indicate that the dimensions are determined at runtime.  I don't think you can use it in the function definition, though.  See C11 [§6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3), especially [¶12](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p12]).